# \textminus in tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, html, textcomp

Is there a way to make `tex4ht` aware of the `\textminus` command?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \textminus 5
\end{document}
```

works as expected with `pdflatex` --- [image: -5] --- but creates a simple hyphen when converting to HTML using

```
mk4ht htlatex texput.tex "xhtml,bib-"
```

I'd like it to print a [Unicode minus sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm) instead; I can print an em rule by saying

```
\def\textminus{--}
```

in the preamble, but I understand that an em rule is something different than a minus sign.

The MWE is also [at GitHub](https://github.com/krlmlr/lm-template/tree/tex4ht-textminus), use `make texput.html` after checking out the `tex4ht-textminus` branch to generate HTML output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no configuration for `textcomp`, so you can provide your own file with suitable redefinition of `\textminus`.

Create file `textcomp.4ht` and place it to directory with your document:

```
\renewcommand\textminus{\HCode{&\#x2212;}}
```

this will output hexadecimal html entity of minus sign. This entity will be later replaced by `tex4ht` command to other character, so it is important to output your file in unicode, because in default case, it is converted back to the `-` char!:

```
htlatex texput "xhtml, bib-, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

---

**edit**

More detailed and more correct setup is described in [Redefine output for a specific TS1 code point (=glyph?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161614/2891)

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I'm targeting `ooffice`, so I don't need to care about UTF-8 anymore, right? Can I define this also in a `.cfg` file?

Comment: I've also seen on the [minus sign page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm) that the HTML entity `&minus;` is equivalent to the hex code; would that still need the UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @krlmlr yes, you can use this also in the cfg file

Comment: @krlmlr in the case of &minus;, I am not sure if it is supported by all viewers, particularly if you are interested in ooffice. but you can try it. in that case you don't need utf-8 encoding

Comment: The `&minus;` literal does work with HTML output, but LibreOffice fails to display it. The explicit Unicode character code works in LibreOffice; for HTML output, it requires the UTF-8 switches as you suggested. Thanks again. I've pushed the fixed MWE to the `tex4ht-textminus-fix` branch. -- Any chance this could be made part of upstream tex4ht?

Comment: @krlmlr in the case if somebody creates configuration file for all `textcomp` symbols, it could be part of tex4ht distribution, I think :)