# Redefine output for a specific TS1 code point (=glyph?)

Tags: font-encodings, tex4ht, textcomp

By now I know how to make [\textminus in tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161446/8057) work, but this does not seem to be enough to [display a proper minus with the `\num` macro of `siunitx`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161446/8057). Joseph Wright provided a workaround, but I'd like to know how to make this work at a more general level.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\pagestyle{empty}

\DeclareTextSymbolDefault\homegrowntextminus{TS1}
\DeclareTextSymbol\homegrowntextminus{TS1}{61}

\begin{document}
  +5 \homegrowntextminus 5
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to configure `tex4ht` so that it prints a proper minus sign (as in the `pdflatex` output below) when converting to HTML **without** knowing or modifying `\homegrowntextminus`?

[image: +5 -5]

GitHub MWE: https://github.com/krlmlr/lm-template/tree/tex4ht-own-textminus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What was showed in [textminus in tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161446/8057) may be good for small changes, but correct process is different. Because `textcomp` is basically font selection package, existing `tex4ht` support is not done by redefining macros in `textcomp.4ht` file, but a special mapping file for font used by `textcomp`, `tcrm.htf` exists. It is located in `texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/jknappen/tc` directory. You can copy this file to your working dir and edit it according to your needs.

These `.htf` files are used by `tex4ht` processor to convert glyphs in the `dvi` file to internal representation, which is then converted using `.4hf` files to actual characters.

Structure of `.htf` files is described in [tex4ht help](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-htf.html). We need to find position of `\textminus` in this file and correct provided definition. It corresponds to position in font encoding. `textcomp` package uses `TS1` font encoding, which is defined in [ts1enc.def](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/astaff/source/src-8.4/third/tetex/texmf/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def). If we search for `\textminus`, we find this line:

```
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textminus}{TS1}{61}
```

This means that `\textminus` is defined on position 61 in the `tcrm.htf` file:

```
 '-' ''            61
```

as you can see, `-` is hardcoded here. We can modify that to use unicode minus instead:

```
 '&#x2212;' ''            61
```

It is best to use this hexadecimal form, because it is used by `.4hf` files to convert to the actual character.

If you compile your file with `htlatex textput` now, and watch output of `tex4ht` command, you will see this line:

```
 (/home/mint/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/iso8859/1/charset/unicode.4hf
```

if you search this file for `x2212`, you will find line:

```
 '&#x2212;' ''  '-' ''
```

this means that unicode minus is converted back to `-`. This is why this work only with unicode output with

```
 htlatex texput "xhtml, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"
```

different `.4hf` file is used now:

```
 (/home/mint/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex4ht/ht-fonts/unicode/charset/unicode.4hf)
```

different definition is used there:

```
 '&#x2212;' '' '\226\\136\\146\' ''
```

this converts entity to the unicode value.

Now back to this question, situation is simpler, as you have added your own symbol at position 61, where original `\textminus` is placed and which we already redefined. So this will work also for `\homegrowntextminus`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to derive the necessary steps and to explain them. It will help me and others in similar situations, and sheds some light on the internals of `tex4ht`. I do hope this can be applied to upstream `tex4ht` -- for my one-shot project, patching `siunitx` has turned out to be faster than patching three of `tex4ht`'s files.