# tex4ht turning the unbreakble space by ~ into unbreakable space in the html

Tags: spacing, tex4ht, html, make4ht

Following my problem concerning spaces from 
[unbreakable (thin) space inside « », for tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282659/unbreakable-thin-space-inside-for-tex4ht/282682#282682)

I edited my message with the following use of the working trick from @michal.h21

```
\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\def\mythinspace{\HCode{<span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span>}}
\newunicodechar{«}{«\mythinspace\ignorespaces}
\newunicodechar{»}{\unskip\mythinspace»}
% \newunicodechar{;}{\mythinspace;}
% \newunicodechar{:}{\mythinspace:}
\fi
\begin{document}
\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\Css{body{background-color:gainsboro;}}
\Css{.fine{
    display: inline-block;
    width:0.125em;}
}

\catcode`\!=\active%
\catcode`\:=\active%
\catcode`\;=\active%
\def\insertthinspace#1{%
  \def#1{\unskip\mythinspace\detokenize{#1}}%
}
\insertthinspace! \insertthinspace: \insertthinspace;
\fi
```

the trick works well, but if I use a numerical code such as `&#8201;` for thin space, instead of its name `&thinsp;` in the modified trick,

```
\def\mythinspace{\HCode{<span style="white-space:nowrap">&#8201;</span>}}
```

then the `make4ht` outputs an error:

```
(d:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newunicodechar/newunicodechar.sty)
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \mythinspace.
<to be read again>
8
l.29 ...{\HCode{<span style="white-space:nowrap">&#8
                                                  201;</span>}}
?
```

**QUESTION 1** : is it possible to enter a **numerical** name in the definition of `\mythinspace` ?

**QUESTION 2**: is it possible to turn every `~` from my `.tex` used as a thin non breakable space, into a

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span>}
```

in my `.html` ???

For instance, there is also the case of the long dash `---` which must have a non breakable space inside it. I attempt to replace the `tilde` by

```
\catcode`\~=\active%
\def\~{\unskip\mythinspace\ignorespaces}%
```

but of course it no longer shows the `tilde` when I need one: Try to compile the code below with active the replacement of the tilde.

```
    \textemdash~my text in long dash~---\\
    ---~asdmy text in long dash~\textemdash

\~{n}ana un tilde \~{}.

\char`\~
```

you see that the `tilde` disappears. even worse,  the `.html` does not show a replacement of the tilde with the `thin non-breakable space`

```
<!--l. 202--><p class="noindent" ><span 
class="cmr-12">—</span><span 
class="cmr-12"> my text in long dash</span><span 
class="cmr-12"> —</span><br 
class="newline" /><span 
class="cmr-12">—</span><span 
class="cmr-12"> asdmy text in long dash</span><span 
class="cmr-12"> —</span>
</p>
<!--l. 205--><p class="noindent" ><span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span><span 
class="cmr-12">nana un tilde</span><span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span><span 
class="cmr-12">.</span>
</p>
<!--l. 207--><p class="noindent" ><span 
class="cmr-12">˜</span>
</p>
```

So is it possible to turn every `~` from my `.tex` used as a thin non breakable space, into a

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">&thinsp;</span>}
```

in my `.html` **while keeping intact the use of `~` when it is used normally, like for accents in `\~{o}`** ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) yes, it is, but you must enter it as hex value:

```
\def\mythinspace{\HCode{<span class="fine">&\#x2009;</span>}}
```

`#` character must be escaped using `\#`. Note that this numerical entity is later replaced with actual unicode character in the HTML. You can revert it with [custom unicode.4hf file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/161614/2891)

2) `~` is already active character, you can redefine it using:

```
\def~{\unskip\mythinspace\ignorespaces}%
```

(so no `\~`)

Complete sample document:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper, 12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[style=french]{csquotes}%
\usepackage{alternative4ht}
\altusepackage{polyglossia}
\altusepackage{fontspec}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\def\semicolon{\detokenize{;}}
\def\mythinspace{\HCode{<span class="fine">&\#x2009;</span>}}
\newunicodechar{«}{«\mythinspace\ignorespaces}
\newunicodechar{»}{\unskip\mythinspace»}
% \newunicodechar{;}{\mythinspace;}
% \newunicodechar{:}{\mythinspace:}
\fi
\begin{document}
\ifx\HCode\undefined \else
\Css{body{background-color:gainsboro;}}
\Css{.fine{
    white-space:nowrap;
  }
}
\Tag{TITLE+}{possibilities for unbreakable space inside « » in HTML}
\catcode`\!=\active%
\catcode`\:=\active%
\catcode`\;=\active%
\def\insertthinspace#1{%
  \def#1{\unskip\mythinspace\detokenize{#1}}%
}
\def~{\unskip\mythinspace\ignorespaces}%
\insertthinspace! \insertthinspace: \insertthinspace;
%unusable solution by @michal.h21
%\def\guillemotleft{\HCode{&laquo;&nbsp;}}
%\def\guillemotright{\unskip\HCode{&nbsp;&raquo;}}
\fi


 ; œ ; Œ ; É ; È ; Ê ; À ; Á ; Å ; Ç

%\euro{}
 ; \oe{} ; \OE{} ; \'{E} ; \`{E} ; \^{E} ; \'{A} ; \`{A} ; \AA{} ; \c{C}

ī \={\i}

My quotes with breakable spaces, once in a html:
« blabla ».

In lualatex, the french spaces for !, ;, : are set properly.
No need for a ~ as in ~!, ~; ~:.

    \textemdash~my text in long dash~---\\
        ---~asdmy text in long dash~\textemdash

        \~{n}ana un tilde \~{}.

        \char`\~        

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I was thinking about trying to use your solution here to allow my code to insert multiple adjacent spaces because in `tex4ht` commands like `\hphantom` don't work, so I thought your redefinition of `~` might allow `~~~~` to produce several spaces manually.  Is it by design that this doesn't work?  Since this question came up readily from a google search, I thought this was the more appropriate place to expand this horizontal space issue than a new question.  Thanks.

Comment: @EngBIRD it should work, I've just tried to add several `~` between some words, they produced several spaces

Comment: My apologies, this indeed works with a `xhtml` compile, but not `html`.

Comment: @EngBIRD that's strange, it works for me also for `html`, even when I compile the document just with `htlatex` without any parameters

Comment: Thanks for checking, time permitting, I will permutate a MWE for a new question with a set of compile options and cfg files and post a new question to determine where the inconsistency lies.  For example, I have determined that inserting multiple and consecutive `~` doesn't work when `ExplSyntax` is `On` (even though it is a valid/successful character to force space between words in this same environment).